# Filtering chart by Datetime

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using SRSS for first time and I have problems with the Datetime format.

In my Database I have a field as Datetime (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss)

When I represent this field in the Report it change at this format (2013-12-30T15:14:27.00+01:00)

I'd like to filter a Chart filtering this value as parameter. The problem is that I don't know how I should parse the format

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Expression in your Field

```
=Format(Now(),"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

put your fielsd at "Now()" and check

Comment: I am using `=Format(Fields!MY_NAME_FIELD.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")` but doesn't work. It prints the string `"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"`

Comment: ok then update with `=CStr(Format(Now(),"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"))` and check.

Comment: with `=CStr(Format(Fields!MY_NAME_FIELD.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"))` appear the same

Comment: one more think check `Fields!MY_NAME_FIELD.Value` is in Datetime format.

Comment: the format value is this: `2013-12-30T15:16:24.00+01:00`

Comment: that means you have to make a correction in SQL Statemant using `Convert(datetime,MY_NAME_FIELD)` b'cose your field is in string datatype not in datetime.

Comment: there is not possible convert to datetime format in the filter?

Comment: `=Format(CDate(Fields!MY_NAME_FIELD.Value),"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")` replace with this

Comment: How should be the format that I need to use to filter the data between 2 days? I am using 2 parameters but I don't know what's the format correct of them. Thanks man you are helping me a lot of.

Comment: That's correct how value's filter? `=CDate("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")`

Comment: i am not getting what you trying to do ??

Comment: I want to filter with parameters between 2 datetimes selectors. I want to take all the entries `=Format(CDate(Fields!AV_FECHA_AVISO.Value),"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")` that it be in the range `PARAM1` `PARAM2`. I don't know how should be the param's format

Comment: so do you have two parameter's List in you Report or not ??

Comment: Yes, I have two parameters as DateTime, but I don't know what should be the value expression of them. I am using `Manually values`

Comment: means every time you are entering the dates not selecting from a calender dropdown...??

Comment: No, the parameters are selectors with manually values, for example, the first parameter I put a selector with two values, TAG1 with value 12/12/2014 00:00:00 and TAG2 with value 31/12/2014 00:00:00. The problem is when I filter with this value, I can't compare String with Datetime.

Comment: Can I use calendar dropdown in SSRS-2008?

Comment: Now I am using parameters fielding with the database. I'd like to make a primary group by column. Here the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617014/grouping-column-by-datetime)