# Grouping column by DateTime

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'd like to grouping a column by a DateTime field (**Months**)

The values of this field are how this: `2014-12-16T12:56:06.32+01:00`

How should be the expression to make a primary group by column?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query :

```
select SUBSTR(COLUMN_NAME,6,2) as "MONTH",count(*) from TABLE_NAME group by 
substr(COLUMN_NAME,6,2);
```

You can add columns in group by as per requirement.

Note : Columns in group by should be present in select.

Comment: I can't modify the query, I want to group in the primary group expression. I think that if I use `=LSet(Fields!MY_DATEFIELD_STRING.Value, 7)` I can get it, but I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

Group by the record in SSRS design .

In the group by record column expression ,give following query

=MonthName(Month(Fields!ListingDate.Value))